# PHP fetch the value from the select html page

Tags: php, html, forms

i have below html code

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST" class="contact">
            <label id="name">
                <h4>name*</h4>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="full name" autofocus/>
            </label>
            <label id="city">
                <h4>city</h4>
            <select name="city">
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                        </select>
            </label>
```

PHP code

```
if($_POST["name"] == null)
{
    echo "<p class='wrong'><strong>wrong: </strong> name is empty</p>";
}
if($_POST["city"] == null)
{
    echo "<p class='wrong'><strong>wrong: </strong> city is empty</p>";
}
```

this to check the null value and always gives the city is empty that means no value selected

Comment: For one, I don't see a closing `</form>` tag.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner is right you won't get any values, and also you should use `if(empty($_POST["name"]))`

Comment: the close form at the end of the form code

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment yet.

Maybe try and close the label before the select.

```
 <label id="city">
   <h4>city</h4>
 </label>         
 <select name="city">
   <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
   <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
 </select>
```

and maybe do

```
<?php echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."<pre>";
```

to see what values are set.

And as others have suggested check of the value is empty()

```
if(!isset($_POST['city'])||empty($_POST['city']))
```

This returns true if city is empty, has no value or true if it doesn't exist.

Hope this helps!

Edit 1:

Also since the php code is probably on the same page, could just omit the action attribute.

```
<form method="POST" class="contact">
 <label for="city">
   <h4>city</h4>
 </label>         
 <select id="city" name="city">
   <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
   <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

also use the for attribute with the ID of the input field you want it to represent

Comment: its not working all the above ,  only the input gives me the output but all select fields nothings

Comment: How re you submitting the form? Also the $_POST variable is only visible after the form has been posted and where is the php code located, on the same page?

Comment: using send bottom , <button type="submit" name="send" id="send">Send<span class="fa fa-send"></span></button>
   </form>
  </div>
  
 and the send to mail.php file

Comment: <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST" class="contact">

Comment: does echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."<pre>" return anything after you post?

Comment: return all other input only select not appear

Comment: where is the mail.php file in relation to the currently executing file PHP_SELF

Comment: i add </form> after the select now gives me the output duplicated with the next input>>> Array
(
    [name] => Ayman
    [name2] => test
    [name3] => 055000000000
    [phone] => 055000000000
    [email] => test@hotmail.com
name3 and phone is duplicated now

Comment: note : the script already working but i just change one option instead of text input i put selected option , this selected option is only not working

Comment: select should work the way you posted it unless your actual implementation is different